# How de find bower version?

Tags: bower

Incredible, I can't handle how to find bower version. Is a comand exist?

I tried to find a command first, secondly, un file showing the version whitout success.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That's an excellent question Joachim. Could you please show us which commands you tried and the file you are talking about ?
Normally you can find bower version in the .bowerrc file https://bower.io/docs/config/ .

Comment: This is not an answer. If you have questions to ask, use the comments section.